# ImageJ API: Usage of Filter in my own Code

Tags: java, api, image-processing, imagej

I would like to filter a image using ImageJ API. The ImageJ libary is correctly connected to my project.

Now I want to process the image with an average filter from the API. How does that work?

```
public Image filterMyImage(ImagePlus imagePlus) 
{
        // IMAGEPLUS FILTERING PROCESS HERE

        return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "average filter" you mean a mean filter with a 3x3 kernel, in which case you could do:

```
ImageProcessor ip = imagePlus.getProcessor();
ip.smooth();
return ip.getBufferedImage();
```

The documentation for the `smooth` method [is here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#smooth%28%29).  If you want a median filter on a 3x3 kernel instead, you could use [the method `medianFilter`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#medianFilter%28%29).

Comment: @haxenmaxen: great - if it was helpful to you, it's appreciated on StackOverflow if you accept the answer by clicking on the "tick" beside the answer.